# No login prompt displayed after updating Ubuntu 10.04, broken gdm

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, login-screen, gdm, udev

So here's what happens:

I updated my system the other day, was prompted for a reboot for the update to complete but was in the middle of working so I delayed it until after I was done. I reboot and it's broken :(.

It appears to boot normally, with the following exceptions:

The purple Ubuntu load screen no longer displays (though it did for the first couple of times I tried to get in).
I hear the login prompt sound, but no login prompt appears. Nor is it simply "invisible" - pressing enter, typing my password, and pressing enter again do nothing.
Normally my Bluetooth mouse is functional at this point, but it is not.

GRUB displays recovery options for my current kernel, and for an older one (2.6.32-24). Trying to boot into .32-24 gives me an error saying "udevadm can't do something while udev is not configured".

So I try solutions listed here: [ubuntu update went wrong, pc doesnt boot, how can I repair it?](https://superuser.com/questions/195786/ubuntu-update-went-wrong-pc-doesnt-boot-how-can-i-repair-it)
Nothing I tried seemed to work, and after further Googling my hunch is that it's a problem with gdm. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I don't know all that much about how Linux/Ubuntu systems work just yet.

Things I'm able to do:
Boot to a live CD

Ctrl-Alt-F2 after that login sound plays brings me to a console login, which I can successfully do (it's how I tried the solutions above). This works only under the current kernel.

A hack I'd be willing to explore is removing the login prompt from the console, but I'd prefer to "simply" fix what's wrong. Like that guy, I need to repair the system rather than reinstall.

System:
Dell Inspiron 1525
Core 2 Duo
Proprietary Driver for Broadcom 43xx wireless

Dual-boot with Windows 7 (which is how I'm posting this, unfortunately I only have this machine and any experimenting requires constant reboots into Windows/brokenbuntu)

Last package installed was Moonlight, but it appeared to install properly.

Kernel: 2.6.32-25

Edit: After working with Karl's suggestions, it seems that the problem is with gdm.

Error exit status 245 when attempting to `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm`, also an error processing gdm when running `sudo apt-get -f install`.

How do I reinstall or repair gdm so that I can get back into my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Ctrl-Alt-F2 prompt, try `sudo gdm-restart` and see if it works and/or provides some useful error messages.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help - appear to be getting somewhere. That brought up:
** (gdm-binary:1642) WARNING **: Failed to acquire org.gnome.DisplayManager
** (gdm-binary:1642) WARNING **: Could not acquire name; bailing out


Being an experimenter, I tried sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm, which returned the following error messages: "dpkg: warning: old pre-removal script returned error exit status 245" and "dpkg: error processing gdm (--configure)". I don't have time to google this right now, but I do think it's a problem with gdm.

Comment: Your reinstall could be failing if you're missing dependencies for some reason.  Try a `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: In addition to a line of "error exit status 245", this returned an "error processing: gdm". sudo apt-get -f install did not complete. So...how do I go about reinstalling gdm if these processes don't seem to work?

Comment: You could get rid of the pre-removal script.  It's at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/gdm.prerm`.  I believe you don't really need it if you are planning to immediately reinstall, but just in case, don't delete it, just move it to your Desktop or something.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything, I get the same `dpkg: error processing gdm (--configure)`.

Comment: I can successfully uninstall gdm. When I try to reinstall, it gives me more `error exit status 245` messages (which I can't find a reference for anywhere), I think when it's trying to configure gdm. I'm almost to the point of giving up and reinstalling - that'll teach me to delay a restart after an update. Gah.

Comment: Wish I could be of more help, but it looks like at this point doing it "the hard way" will actually be easier.

Comment: It occurred to me on the way home tonight - I know that I use a proprietary driver for my wireless, and it definitely doesn't work until the machine is fully booted. I try to ping say, google.com, and it immediately doesn't resolve, so I don't think it's initialized. I do have the 10.04 distro CD (downloaded around 8/28/10) in the drive, could it be grabbing gdm to reinstall from there and that version is incompatible with the updates?

Comment: It's worth a try.

Comment: No dice. Backed up my files, looks like I'll be reinstalling this evening. Thanks for your help though, I greatly appreciate the attempt.

Comment: This is why I keep my /home on a separate partition. In this case, I'd set up a new installation and keep the old one and hack away at it until I got it fixed or completely ruined it.

Answer (score 3):

I found some info [here](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2011/04/ubuntu-1004-no-login-prompt.html), which suggests it is related with zlib - I can confirm that in my case it was zlib issue. However, I needed the zlib 1.2.5 compiled from source for other software, so I found these solutions:

1. Upgrade Ubuntu (in 11.04 it does not occur, but it does not use gdm afaik?), but it is not really usefull advice
2. Go to terminal (crtl+alt+f1), login, and run `sudo apt-get install nodm` and then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nodm` choosing to use nodm and providing one's login. Honestly, I've first edited the file `/etc/default/nodm manually`, but ran the `dpkg-reconfigure` soon afterwards.

Then restart. There are still many major problems with gnome desktop, so it's rather whole Gnome problem, than only gdm login screen.

Summarizing, I guess update to newer version of Ubuntu or changing to kde + kdm for example are best solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Once the system boots to the first screen with no login prompt:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to the text mode login
2. Log in to text mode with your credentials
3. Change to the directory where the zlib source is located
4. Run the command `sudo make uninstall`
5. Now reboot using `sudo reboot`

This worked for me when I had the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on Centos6.3.  I list my solution below which is inspired by misiak and [[startx error when setting up X server on archlinux]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33825/startx-error-when-setting-up-x-server-on-archlinux).

first by

> $ sudo ldd /usr/bin/Xorg | grep libz

I get

> libz.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00172000)

`/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1` link to `/usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.7`(may be my new install)

I think `Xorg` should depend on `/lib/libz.so.1.2.3`(original install).

Then I

> $ cd /usr/local/lib
>
> $ sudo mv libz.so.1 libz.so.1.bak
>
> $ sudo ln -s /lib/libz.so.1 libz.so.1
>
> $ sudo reboot

done!

Answer (score 0):

That message “udev is not configured” makes me think something went wrong doing the updates, and your system has been left in a semi-functional state. Here “configured” has a technical meaning: installing a Debian package means first unpacking its files, then “configuring” it to update configuration files, regenerate caches, etc.

On the command line, try doing

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If this still throws errors, try running it a couple more times. This won't make the errors go away, but might make more packages into a usable state. Then do

```
sudo dpkg --configure udev linux-image-generic xserver-xorg gdm
```

to insist on configuring the most important packages.

If at that point you still have unconfigured packages, post the error messages. If you're still unable to access SU from Linux, do

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a >/media/disk9/dpkg--configure.log
```

(replace `/media/disk9` by wherever your Windows disk is mounted) and post the contents of `dpkg--configure.log` from Windows.

If `dpkg --configure -a` succeeds and you still have trouble, my hypothesis was wrong.

Comment: Aye, I'm somewhat familiar with what configure means in this case, but I already ran a "dpkg --configure -a" (and some of the other dpkg-reconfigure stuff in that other question) and didn't receive error messages while doing so. So I assume they completed just fine.